# GoodData.UI - Unreliable event firing for initial filter values on Windows Chrome

Tags: gooddata

Today we released to our customers the first customised chart built with the GoodData UI JS SDK. 
On Chrome and Firefox on Mac and Linux we couldn't find any issues. 
On Windows Chrome, however, it is very unstable. On two company machines the loading of the chart didn't work at all. 
On a Google Cloud Windows Virtual Machine it works most of the time, but not always.

We only render the chart after we received the GD JS event which informs us about the initial filter settings of the page. 
Our guess is that this event is not received (and maybe not even fired from GD?) consistently on Windows Chrome.

@GoodData: Could you please let us know if our assumption might be correct, and, very important, give us an estimation about how long it will take to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. There is a problem with the event which is not complete. It is a bug, which GooData plan to fix on July 3rd.